# How to read data of a nested dictionary in json request

Tags: python, flask

I'm changing up the way I send JSON requests to my flask server by doing a nested dictionary.

I was originally sending the dictionary below from my iOS device:

```
["email": email, "password": password, "business":business]
```

and reading the data on my flask server by doing the following:

```
data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
form = RegistrationForm(data)
```

The iOS side has been changed to:

```
userDict = ["email": email, "password": password, "business": business]
["userInfo": userDict] //sending this dictionary to flask
```

Not sure how I'm suppose to tailor my flask code to work with this so that I can still use the form to validate the data received.  So far this hasn't been working:

```
d=MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
data = d.get('userInfo')
form = RegistrationForm(data)

email = StringField('email', validators=[Required()])
business = StringField('business', validators=[Required()])
password = PasswordField('password', validators=[Required()])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:

```
    d=MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
    data = d.get('userInfo')
    data2 = MultiDict(mapping=data)
    form = RegistrationForm(data2)
```

Not very elegant, but it did the job.